# Can I create a map of {instanceid: valueOfNameTag} using terraform data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, terraform

I want to get a map using terraform data which has the following structure:

```
{
  instance-id(e.g. i-xxxx): ValueOfNameTag(e.g. MongoDB)
}
```

I can get the instance details individually like below

```
data "aws_instance" "test" {
  instance_id = "i-0ecb3c2fb4436b6fe"
}
```

But don't know hot to do it for all and create a map out of it.

Comment: This exists in the Terraform state if you are managing the resource. Are you not managing the resource?

Comment: @MattSchuchard No, I'm not managing the instances. They are already there. I want to use data source to get the details and then create a map that I can use.

Comment: How are you storing the list of IDs for the instances?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I'm using data "aws_instances". This returns list of instance ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a three step process. The first step (already exists according to comments) is to retrieve the desired list of instance IDs:

```
data "aws_instances" "this" {
  # arguments to select specific subset of instances
}
```

The `list(string)` of instances IDs will be stored in the exported resource attribute `ids`.

The second step is to retrieve the tags of each individual instance:

```
data "aws_instance" "this" {
  # iterate over subset of desired instances by ID
  for_each = toset(data.aws_instances.this.ids)

  instance_id = each.value
}
```

The tags for each instance will be stored in the exported resource attribute `tags`, and therefore can be accessed via the namespace `data.aws_instance.this["<instance id>"].tags` as per normal in Terraform HCL2 DSL.

The third step is to perform a data transformation to construct a `map` where the key is the instance ID, and the value of a tag is the value. The example given in the question was for the value of the `Name` tag, so that is what we will use here in the example:

```
locals {
  instance_name = { for id, attributes in data.aws_instance.this : id => attributes.tags["Name"] }
}
```

and the desired `map` of instance IDs to their respective `Name` tag will be stored in `local.instance_name` as expected. You could alternatively iterate over the `data.aws_instances.this.ids` `list(string)` in a `for` lambda expression and map to the exported attributes from the `data.aws_instance.this[each.value].tags["Name"]`, but the above algorithm is slightly cleaner and slightly more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, Matt! I have one more issue, you might wanna take a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/69454592/10065458